# Change to UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate definition for Swift 3 prevents transition

Tags: ios, swift, transition, viewcontroller

I have been following a tutorial to add custom transitions, written for Swift 2:, but my custom transitions do not replace the existing ones.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 3 its really important to use `animationController( forPresented:` instead of `animationControllerForPresented (` in your delegate definition.

```
extension DataViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
            return PresentMenuAnimator() //your replacement
    }
}
```

Otherwise your suggested animator just gets ignored.

This is not flagged up by the autocorrect code in Xcode.

Comment: If the compiler did not flag that your method signatures were wrong (for Swift 3), you should file a bug report.

Comment: I will be doing that

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by Swift 3 *renamification*. In particular, the Clang Importer has trouble with optional protocol methods: the compiler doesn't always match up your old declaration with the new, renamified declaration. Thus, your method becomes a useless function that will never be called: you don't get any warning from the compiler about the problem because the method you have failed to implement correctly is optional, but at runtime, Objective-C does not see your declared function as the method it is looking for, so it doesn't call it.

Here are some tips I've developed for noticing and solving this problem:

- Always make your declaration in an extension explicitly adopting the protocol. The compiler will *certainly* not see your methods if you don't do that. (I regard this as a bug in Swift, and have filed it.)
- Put the selection inside the function name and look at the Quick Help inspector on the right. If you don't see the help — that is, if all you see is your function declaration — you have not matched the delegate function correctly.
- Look at the docs! In this case, https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate shows the renamified signatures. And so do the headers: just command-clicking the term UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate would have shown them to you.
- When in doubt, stick the Objective-C name of the method in front of yours with an `@objc(...)` attribute. That allows Objective-C to see your method. It's a temporary stopgap but at least it would have gotten your code working again.